# Dynamics CRM Online and Web API : Method Tunneling through POST

Tags: odata, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I'm using Dynamics CRM 2016 Online and I want to update an entity (a contact for example) using the Web API (odata 4.0) endpoint.

I use Fiddler to test the request. Here are the details of the request :

```
PATCH https://XXXXXXXXXXX/api/data/v8.0/contacts(6b902ae1-19ed-e511-80e3-5065f3890551)
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: XXXXXXXXX
Content-Length: 54
Accept: application/json
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
OData-Version: 4.0
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXX

{
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe"
}
```

It works well. The problem is that the client does not support the PATCH verb.

An odata endpoint can handle this limitation by using POST and a additional HTTP header. Quote from the documentation :

> In order to help work-around this limitation, OData servers can
>   support method tunneling through POST. The methods that can be
>   executed through tunneling are MERGE, PUT and DELETE.
>
> To issue a request with method tunneling a client sets up a request
>   with body and headers as needed, but uses POST as the HTTP method
>   instead of the actual required one. It then adds one more header,
>   "X-HTTP-Method", and gives it the value MERGE, PUT or DELETE.
>
> Servers must check if POST requests have the X-HTTP-Method header set
>   to one of the valid values and if so execute the rest of the request
>   as if the header value was the actual HTTP method for it.

But when I try to execute the same request using POST instead of PATCH and with the additional header, I receive a error :

```
message=Unmapped Request found, PathTemplate:~/entityset/key, HttpVerb:POST
```

I also try the X-HTTP-Method-Override header as described [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPUTOrDELETENotAllowedUseXHTTPMethodOverrideForYourRESTServiceWithASPNETWebAPI.aspx) but same result.

Is there a mistake from my side or the endpoint does not support this feature ? Thanks.

Comment: CRM's Web API endpoint is definitely not a complete implementation of the OData protocol, so if your POST request received that response, then that's a strong indication that the endpoint doesn't support that part of the protocol. :/

Answer (score 2):

Use PATCH (but you say this one is not being supported).

Use PUT (note with PUT you have to specify the attribute URL/{attribute}, which forces you to make for each attribute a PUT call, not the perfect way but its something)

This worked for me instead of a POST.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607664.aspx